# Did I do this growth rate question correctly? If not, then can you explain why its wrong?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

A certain population grows at a rate proportional to the square of the population. If the population increases from $10,000$ to $15,000$ in three years, what is it at the end of t years?
My answer to this part of the question is: $\frac{-1}{y} = \frac{t}{90000} - \frac{1}{10000}$, where $y =$ population and $t =$ time.

Then the question asks, How long can it grow at this rate before exploding beyond all bounds?
My answer is when $t = 9$, because you can re-arrange the equation as so: $y = \frac{90000}{(t-9)}$ and $y \to \infty$ when $t \to 9$.

I am not entirely sure if my answer is correct, so I would hope if I can get feedback.

Comment: If you are in need of an immediate response, I suggest looking for similar problem in the search bar on the top right. You will be surprised how many questions similar to yours may have been asked previously.

Answer (score 1):

I would tidy up your formula a bit: $y = ...$ rather than $-1/y = ... $  Also, it would good to mention some more of your reasoning, e.g. I hope that you started with something like this:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = kx^2$$

I get $$y = \frac{1}{k(C - x)^2}$$

Substituting initial values, I get:

$$y = \frac{90000}{9 - x}$$

So, I agree that the population explodes at year 9.